# Add more columns to a view with subselect

Tags: sql-server, view, subquery

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2012, I am trying to create a new view that will return the real start and finish of a line when the descriptions match.

I have a table that looks like this

```
+----+-------+-------+-----+
| ID | desc  | start | end | 
+----+-------+-------+-----+
|  1 | line1 |     0 | 100 |
|  2 | line2 |     0 | 100 |
|  3 | line2 |   101 | 200 | 
+----+-------+-------+-----+
```

I want to add 2 more columns so that when the desc matches, it returns the 0 from ID 2 and the 200 from ID 3 like this:

```
+----+-------+-------+-----+------------+----------+
| ID | desc  | start | end | real_start | real_end |
+----+-------+-------+-----+------------+----------+
|  1 | line1 |     0 | 100 |          0 |      100 |
|  2 | line2 |     0 | 100 |          0 |      200 |
|  3 | line2 |   101 | 200 |          0 |      200 |
+----+-------+-------+-----+------------+----------+
```

My syntax so far:

```
CREATE VIEW tableview1 
AS 
     SELECT 
         ID, desc,
         start, end,
         (???) as real_start,
         (???) as real_end 
     FROM 
         linetable 
     WHERE 
         condition;
```

I'm at a loss as to how to group and compare the two lines when the description matches and select the lowest of the two. I'll play around on my own and update the thread.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or data. No one can copy and paste in order to help you. [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed. Also, [why to avoid pictures of code...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5790584)

Answer (score 0):

Your sub-selects could simply be MIN()/MAX() for that `desc`

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work, can anyone confirm?

```
    CREATE VIEW tableview1 
AS 
     select 
     t1.ID, t1.desc,
     t1.start, t1.end,
     (select min(start)
        from linetable z
        where z.desc = t1.desc) as real_start,
     (select min(end)
        from linetable z
        where z.desc = t1.desc) as real_end
     from    
     (SELECT 
         ID, desc,
         start, end,
     FROM 
         linetable 
     WHERE 
         condition) as t1
```